# How to bind different entries to Return key

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to do something very simple, lets say I have 2 entries,
First Name:
Second Name:

When I press enter in one, it executes both functions. I'm trying to have it where I just press enter in only 1 of the entries, and it will execute only that entry. How can I do that?
This is the code

```
root = tk.Tk()

firstLabel = tk.Label(root, text="First Name:")
firstEntry = tk.Entry(root)

secondLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Last Name: ")
secondEntry = tk.Entry(root)

def save(event=None):
    print("HELLO")
    first_value = firstEntry.get()
    print(first_value)


def save2(event=None):
    print("HELLO2")
    second_value = secondEntry.get()
    print(second_value)


root.bind('<Return>', save, firstEntry)
root.bind('<Return>', save2, secondEntry)

root.mainloop()
```

Now when I press enter in either, it prints both HELLOs, how can I set it up so it only executes the def for that one only.

Comment: It's because Tkinter cannot know which entry you want to get the callback on. You have to bind the key press to the entries, not to the main window

Comment: Ah, makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

firstLabel = tk.Label(root, text="First Name:")
firstEntry = tk.Entry(root)

secondLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Last Name: ")
secondEntry = tk.Entry(root)

firstLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
firstEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)
secondLabel.grid(row=2, column=1)
secondEntry.grid(row=2, column=2)

def save(event=None):
    print("HELLO")
    first_value = firstEntry.get()
    print(first_value)


def save2(event=None):
    print("HELLO2")
    second_value = secondEntry.get()
    print(second_value)


firstEntry.bind('<Return>', save)
secondEntry.bind('<Return>', save2)

root.mainloop()
```

You have to bind to each entry not to the root (as @Programmer said).